# $_SESSION variable not setting value

Tags: php, session-variables, var-dump

[**RESOLVED**] 
In my login.php, several `$_SESSION` variables are set.
 I've recently added in another = `$_SESSION['darkM'] = false;`.
 Doing a `var_dump($_SESSION);` (Results below), my other variable's values are set perfectly but this **one just will not**!

I've tried setting it to a *string* instead (`'test'`) but still returns empty in the var_dump. It is only this variable that will not set.
I've checked my error_log and there is nothing! Just to clear up, `session_start();` is already set just above where I declare my variables. Any idea why this could be happening?

----- EDIT -----

**Login.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

   // Store data in session variables
   $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true; // No error
   $_SESSION["tenant"] = $tenant; // No error
   $_SESSION['darkM'] = false; // Also tried setting to 'test'
```

**VAR_DUMP($_SESSION)** :

```
Array ( [loggedin] => 1 [tenant] => Coledon  [darkM] => )
```

## RESOLVED

I have no idea why this made any difference, but I changed the variable **from** `$_SESSION['darkM']` **to** `$_SESSION['dark_mode']`.
Doing another `var_dump` the new result is:
array(1) {
['dark_mode']=>
bool(false)
}

So I no longer have an issue, but still have no idea why this happened? There was no typing issues/hidden characters.
 Also if anyone has this same problem please see **navnath**'s & **Reflective**'s answers - important to remember!

Comment: You should share your code instead of just description

Comment: So by this "`session_start();` is already set just above where I declare my variables", you're saying you've called `session_start()` before setting this `$_SESSION['darkM'] = false;.` right? If not, that would cause the scenario that you are describing.

Comment: @Salvino -- That is correct yes. I also thought that was my mistake, but its placed correctly :(

Comment: @navnath -- I will edit my question now and share code

Comment: @Coledon_Projects Use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` for debugging purposes (the output you get is from `print_r()`). Also [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the problem you have.

Comment: Did you try to re enter the full line in case there is some invisible character that prevent code execution. Did you also try to put it in first position ?

Comment: Just to make sure you actually tried what you're showing: create a new file `test.php`, _manually type this code over_, and run it (over localhost, of course, not from file). Because I suspect you didn't, and you'll see something different happening compared to what your post claims happens for this code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Yes recreating this in Localhost worked. But I need this to work on the actual server. I deleted my code and completely retyped and got the same issue.

Comment: @PtitXav -- I deleted my code and completely retyped and got the same issue. I really have no idea why this error is happening.

Comment: Everyone I've updated my question - changing the variable name resolved the problem. BUT when I tried the old name again, the problem came back...

Comment: @Coledon_Projects running on localhost means "running it locally with a full server setup so that it behaves the same as your stage/prod instance". If your localhost setup doesn't mirror your prod instance, that will certainly be the first thing to solve before debugging any future problems.

Answer (score 2):

No problem at all, just `print_r` treats `false` differently than you may expect. Use `var_dump` as it shows the value and type of the variables instead of converting them to string which `print_r` does.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['darkMode'] = false;
    print_r($_SESSION);
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [darkMode] => 
)

array(1) {
  ["darkMode"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Reflective, that is correct. I also tried changing the variable's value to a string and it threw the same error.

Comment: I don't this answer helps in anyway, sorry @Reflective. Reason being that @Coledon_Projects has already mentioned in the question that he tried setting a string value `test` for that same variable and it was not being set. Ignoring the fact that he also mentioned the use of `var_dump` instead of `print_r` in code.  I'm not downvoting this, but I really think it's just verbose and unnecessary.

Comment: Everyone I've updated my question - changing the variable name resolved the problem. BUT when I tried the old name again, the problem came back...

Comment: @Reflective yeah I understand. I'm just saying it shouldn't have been an answer. But more of a comment against the question. As you see, it's still not answering why the variable was not showing rather it's just diverting the poster to a coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

[Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer navnath, that is correct. I also tried changing the variable's value to a string and it threw the same error.

Comment: What is the error now? Still you are not getting value for it?

Comment: Just checked again, the result is: `array(1) {  ["darkM"]=> }`  -- I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to report all errors

Comment: Everyone I've updated my question - changing the variable name resolved the problem. BUT when I tried the old name again, the problem came back...